# Why I can't delete key at HKLM?

Tags: registry, c++builder

I'm use `RegDelnode(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Test"));`
It's from MSDN and it worked good for HKCU, but i'm think that i must to set privileges. If I right, which privileges i must to set on?
Program write on c++ builder (if that helps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify stuff in the `HKLM` branch your application must run with administrator privileges. Otherwise, changes to this branch are not permitted.

Comment: I know privileges as SE_BACKUP_NAME and SE_RESTORE_ And how i could to permit changes for delete key. With which function?